# maven repo contains wrong cglib source jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, cglib

I have encountered a problem with cglib 2.2.2 sources jar in maven central repo. It contains following top-level entries:

```
lib
META_INF
src
build.xml
README
LICENCE
NOTICE
```

Is it done intentionally or it is malformed sources package? I have repacked this jar and moved source code from src directory to upper level, and all source code for cglib became accessible, before that some cglib classes did not have source attachments, however sources jar contained that classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise issues with Maven Central [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL). Also looks like someone raised this issue [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3564669&group_id=56933&atid=482368) at the cglib sourceforge site.